# Putting a TWS file dependencies on AWS S3 stored file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, tivoli-work-scheduler

I have an ETL application which is suppose to migrate to AWS infra. The scheduler being used in my application is Tivoli Work Scheduler and we want to use the same on cloud as well which has file dependencies.

Now when we move to aws , the files to be watched will land in S3 Bucket. Can we put the OPEN dependency for files in S3? If yes, What would be the hostname ( HOST#Filepath ) ?

If Not, what services should be aligned to serve the purpose. I have both time as well as file dependency in my SCHEDULES.

Eg. The file might get uploaded on S3 at 1AM. AT 3 AM my schedule will get triggered, look for the file in S3 bucket. If present, starts execution and if not then it should wait as per other parameters on tws.

Any help or advice would be nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, job triggered at 3am will identify all files uploaded within last e.g. 24 hours.

You can list all s3 files to list everything uploaded within specific period of time.

Better solution would be to create S3 upload trigger which will send information to SQS and have your code inspect the depth (number of messages) there and start processing the files one by one. An additional benefit would be an assurance that all items are processed without having to worry about time overalpse.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The issue here is that I will need a time dependency as well since ETL apps are so designed that incase the file lands late I need to wait for specific time. TWS provides this wait feature with OPEN on a file and take appropriate answere.

Comment: Is it possible to use S3 event/trigger and lambda to write a file on EBS?I have not tried it but just a thought